# Debugging or mapping out a large state machine?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, state-machine, automata

I'm trying to debug a chunk of code that's mostly a straightforward 16-state state machine, although there are some cases where the transitions are not very simple (the data the state changes operate on are about 200 bytes of data in a couple C++ classes).

We're finding the machine ending up in a "final" state much earlier than expected. Since I'm not yet intimately familiar with the code, I'm hoping I can try to make out the different states and transitions in a way that will make it easier for me to quickly identify and debug the different transition paths.

Are there any useful tools or techniques for mapping out a state machine like this?

It might be worth noting that I'm doing this from a reverse-engineering standpoint, so there is no planning documentation for the system available to me.

Comment: How do you identify the current state while debugging? If it's just 16 states why not draw them on a piece of paper and note the index or whatever the program uses to store the state?

Comment: State machines are hard to debug with just breakpoints.  Logging is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into formal model checking tools, such as [UPPAAL](http://www.uppaal.com). This tool can be used for modelling and verification of any system that can be modelled as networks of timed automata - this includes state machines. I have used it previously to verify e.g. invariants and reachability of possible states.